# Find ways to get to a number of levels

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, loops, logic

I got this problem on CoderByte. The requirement was to find a number of ways. I found solutions for that in StackOverflow and other sites. But moving ahead, **I need all possible ways as well to reach the Nth step.**

Problem description: There is a staircase of N steps and you can climb either 1 or 2 steps at a time. You need to count and return the total number of unique ways to climb the staircase. The order of steps taken matters.

For Example,

Input: N = 3

Output: 3

Explanation: There are 3 unique ways of climbing a staircase of 3 steps :{1,1,1}, {2,1} and {1,2}

Note: There might be another case that a person can take 2 or 3 or 4 steps at a time (I know that's realistically not possible but trying to add scalability to the input steps in the code)

I'm unable to find the right logic to get all the ways possible. It's useful if I get the solution in Python, but it's not a strict requirement though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a minimal solution using `itertools` library:

```
from itertools import permutations, chain

solve = lambda n: [(1,)*n] + list(set(chain(*[permutations((2,)*i + (1,)*(n-2*i)) for i in range(1, n//2+1)])))
```

For your example input:

```
> solve(3)
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

---

**How it works?**

It's easier to see what's happening if we take a step backwards:

```
def solve(n):
    combinations = [(1,)*n]
    for i in range(1, n//2+1):
        combinations.extend(permutations((2,)*i + (1,)*(n-2*i)))
    return list(set(combinations))
```

The most trivial case is the one where you take one step at a time, so *n* steps: `(1,)*n`. Then we can look for how many double steps could we take at most, and that's the floor of *n* divided by 2: `n//2`. Then we iterate over the possible double steps: try to add a double step each iteration `(2,)*i`, filling the remaining space with single steps `(1,)*(n-2*i)`.

The function [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) from itertools will generate all the possible permutations of single and double steps for that iteration. With an input of (1,1,2), it will generate (1,1,2), (1,2,1) and (2,1,1). At the end we use the trick of converting the result to a `set` in order to remove duplicates, then converting it back into a list.

---

**Generalization for any amount and length of steps (not optimal!)**

One liner:

```
from itertools import permutations, chain, combinations_with_replacement

solve = lambda n, steps: list(set(chain(*[permutations(sequence) for sequence in chain(*[combinations_with_replacement(steps, r) for r in range(n//min(steps)+1)]) if sum(sequence) == n])))
```

Example output:

```
> solve(8, [2,3])
[(3, 2, 3), (2, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 2)]
```

Easier to read version:

```
def solve(n, steps):
    result = []
    for sequence_length in range(n//min(steps)+1):
        sequences = combinations_with_replacement(steps, sequence_length)
        for sequence in sequences:
            if sum(sequence) == n:
                result.extend(permutations(sequence))
    return list(set(result))
```

Comment: Thanks, @stjernaluiht. This is a simplified solution and it works well. I was wondering what if the use-case changes to climbing 2 or 3 steps in place of 1 or 2 at a time. Then the default case of 2 steps at a time might not work when n is an odd number in your code. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! The generalization of this problem for an arbitrary number of steps is actually an _NP-hard problem_, concretely a variation of the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). This means that the time until a solution is found grows exponentially with the size of the input.

Comment: I added to the answer the generalization that would work with any number and length of steps, but it's far from an optimal solution.

Comment: Yes, this works for all input cases. Thanks for your quick response. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def solve(n) :
    if (n == 0):
        return [[]]
    else:
        left_results = []
        right_results = []

        if (n > 0):
            left_results = solve(n - 1)
            for res in left_results: # Add the current step to every result
                res.append(1)

        if (n > 1):
            right_results = solve(n - 2)
            for res in right_results: # Same above
                res.append(2)

        return left_results + right_results
```

I think there is a better way to do this using dynamic programming but I don't know how to do that. Hope it helps anyway.